# Paused Workflow not Resuming

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a workflow that runs on a list item and pauses until a given date but it sometimes doesn't resume once that date has past. I say "sometimes" because I've seen this workflow work in the past. (It only exists on a dev server right now.)

Below is an example of the last two entries in the workflow history, along with a screen shot of the system time from the server. It's well past the time it should have run. I tried restarting the SharePoint Timer Service. Any ideas on why it's not running? All I can think is that since I'm the only person using the dev server things go to "sleep" although I would think that shouldn't affect the timer service.

[image: Image showing workflow history and system time]

Comment: If you click on "Pausing until 12/8/2016", what does it say in that screen?

Comment: It's not a link. All that happens is that the row gets selected. The only thing that's a link is the user name (in this case "System Account").

Comment: Which version of the workflow are you using new 2013 or the 2010?

Comment: Using a 2010 version of the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If workflow is pause and after that server is restarted/iisreset/application pool restart, in SharePoint Workflow will not restarted sometimes.